# What's the point of placing calls-to-action above the fold on sales pages?

Tags: call-to-action, marketing

Since you haven't even presented your product yet, why put the "Subscribe now" or "Buy now" above the fold?

Shouldn't it be placed last, after the actual offer?

Answer (score 1):

"Buy now" or any other Call-To-Action (CTA) button are usually the main focus for the companies website. **These buttons are how they convert sales.**

As such, standard practice tells us that CTA buttons should be placed at the top so that it's one of the first things the user notices.

> "Oh hey, that's where I press if I want to buy the product, good to know, I'm going to read more."

### But,

it's shown that the more CTA buttons you have on your web page, the more chance you'll have of getting those conversions!

So for the best practice [Use Multiple Call to Action Buttons](https://www.invespcro.com/blog/multiple-call-to-actions-increased-conversions-by-20/), both above the fold and in a timely manner around product descriptions.

It doesn't have to be one or the other, it works best when you use more!

Answer (score 1):

-> Because some users are returning users already informed what the product is. For them is convenient to see button right away. 
-> Because if you place that button decent and it does not damage your design, its not bad to have it after multipole sections so users have it always available.